# The greatest value of |z+1| if $z$ lies in the interior or on the boundary of a circle

Tags: complex-numbers

If a complex number $z$ lies in the interior or on the boundary of a circle of radius $3$ units and centre $(-4,0)$, find the greatest value of $|z+1|$.

**Solution:**

$|z-(-4+i0)|=|z+4|\leq 3$, So
$$
|z+1|=|z+4+(-3)|\leq|z+4|+|-3|\leq3+3=6
$$

**My Approach:**

From geometry we know the farthest point corresponds to the complex number is $(-7,0)$, ie. $|z|\leq7$
$$
|z+1|\leq|z|+|1|\leq7+1=8
$$

What really is missing in my approach ? Why am I not getting the greatest upper bound ?

Comment: It cannot harm to draw a picture here. Also note that - if $z$ is on the disk you mention, so with center $(-4,0)$ - then $z+1$ is on a sortlike disk with center $(-3,0)$.

Comment: @drhab i think i understand that. For $|z+1|$ the given circle is pushed rightward, which gives the same circle with center $(-3,0)$. But anything wrong in taking $|z|\leq 7$ and proceeding with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $|z+1|\le |z|+1$, equality only holds when $z$ is *real and positive* (i.e. collinear with $1$ and on the same side), which never occurs ! Hence the bound isn't tight.

Comment: could you pls explain on this context. how can u say z and 1 never b collinear ?

Comment: @ss1729: no, *positive* never occurs !

Comment: ohh thts right. $\arg{z}\neq\arg{1}$ right, since z is always in the circle on the left half. $|z+4+(-3)|\leq|z+4|+|-3|$ since z+1 can be negative. So I think I need to always consider the validity of equality when applying the triangular inequality for complex number inorder to avoid getting a different bound in similar problems, right ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overthinking this. If $z$ is in an geometrical area $A$, then $\tilde z=z+1$ is in a similar area, just shifted by $1$. So, simply find the $\max |\cdot|$ for that circle of radius three around $-3$.

Now, maximum absolute value means maximum distance from the origin $0$, which happens to be part of this convex geometrical shape, and quite obviously, on a circle, the point farthest away from another point is that diagonally across the circle, so it's $-6$ with an absolute value of $6$.

Comment: tht i can see. in |z+1| everything is pushed rightward by $1$. So it'll b the same circle for $z$ but with the center $(-3,0)$. But what's going wrong with the approach I mentioned above?..anything wrong in taking $|z|\leq 7$?

Comment: no, same result. $\tilde z = -6\implies z = -7$.

Comment: actually my doubt is why I am i not getting the required result when taking $|z|\leq 7$ and proceeding further ?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Your question only derives an upper bound. It could just as well have derived 1000 as upper bound – there's nothing saying these are tight bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, $|z+1|$ is just the distance between $z$ and $-1$.
If $z$ lies in the circle $|z+4|\leq3$, as you said, the point that is as far as possible from $-1$ is $z=-7$ with distance $|-7-(-1)|=6$.

Answer (score 0):

You fixed $z = -7$. There is little point in using triangle inequality for bounding now as it will necessarily produce "bad" bound. This is because $|z+1| = |-7 +1| = 6$, but you deliberately "forgot" that you fixed $z=-7$, and only remembered $|z| = 7$. For all the triangle inequality cares, $z$ could just as likely be $7$, and thus $|z+1| \leq 8$.

Instead, what you need to argue is that if $z$ maximizes $\{|z|\mid |z+4|\leq 3\}$, then $z+1$ maximizes $\{|z+1|\mid |z+4|\leq 3\}$, but although it can be done, it looks bit sloppy. Much better to do what Marcus Müller did, or follow the solution you were given. Just note that although that solution correctly gives upper bound, it misses argument that the bound can be achieved, but this is where you just say: "Look. Works for $z= -7$."